# Get information to create ALTER TABLE ADD FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

How to get the information to update an already existing foreign key..

When updating a foreign key referemce in phpmyadmin this query is sent to the server

```
ALTER TABLE `dimension` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`test_id`) REFERENCES `db`.`test`
(`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT;
```

But how do I get the status `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` to sending and updating the alter table query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't.  You have to drop the existing foreign key constraint and add a new one.

However, you can fetch the existing ***`reference_option`*** from the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/referential-constraints-table.html):

```
SELECT CONSTRAINT_NAME, UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME, UPDATE_RULE, DELETE_RULE
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE  CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'dimension'
   AND REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'test'
```

Or else from [`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/show-create-table.html):

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE dimension
```

Comment: yes, but how can I retrieve the ON DELETE and ON UPDATE status from an existing key?

Comment: Added `CONSTRAINT_NAME` in the Select list, as you may have more than one FKs from one table to another.

Comment: @eggyal You may also want to add `AND UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE()` in the conditions (that's the database of the referenced table (`test` here) and the `UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME` in the Select list (that's the referenced Unique (or Primary) Key (in test here).

Comment: @ypercube:  All true enough!  Thanks for thinking so thoroughly about it.  :)